# Shading a region of the plane using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to create a simple diagram of the xy plane where the region y>-1 is shaded. I searched this forum to try to find a way to do so, and I (almost) found a solution using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-5,
ymax=5
]
\addplot[name path=line1,dashed] {-1};
\addplot[name path=line2,draw=none] {5};
\addplot[gray!15]   fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, what I end up with when I compile is a diagram which looks like the following:[image]

Why is it the case that the axes are invisible (and that the arrows from the ends of the axes have disappeared)? How can I fix this?

Comment: welcome to the site. You can search for `set layers` in the manual

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `axis on top` option:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-5,
ymax=5,
axis on top,
]
\addplot[name path=line1,dashed] {-1};
\addplot[name path=line2,draw=none] {5};
\addplot[gray!15]   fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```